# Appending and detaching dynamically created inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons:

- `fixed_price_option` (**Selected** by default.)
- `variable_price_option` (**Disabled** by default)

I also have two types of inputs:

- `fixed_price_input` (**Visable** by default. Only one occurance.)
- `variable_price_input` (Not present in code as it has to be added dynamically. One or more occurances.)

When `fixed_price_option` is selected an input called `fixed_price_input` should be visable and included when later running .serialize().

When `fixed_price_option` is selected no `variable_price_input`´s should be visible or included when later running .serialize().

`variable_price_option` should only be selectable when the difference between two date inputs are more than 12 months. (this I have solved)

When `variable_price_option` is selected there should be **one more** `variable_price_input`´s visable as there are whole years between the two date inputs (i.e. durationMonths + 1). They also need to be included when later running .serialize() so they need to have names like `price_year_1`, `price_year_2`, `price_year_3` and so on, depending on how many whole years there are between the two date inputs.

When `variable_price_option` is selected `fixed_price_input` should not be visible or included when later running .serialize().

I have supplied the code as far as I have come. The missing logic needs to be put in the event handler at the bottom of the js code.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

**-- UPDATE --**

My question needed clarification:

What I'm struggling with is to toggle the existence of the two types of inputs (`fixed_price_input` and `variable_price_input`) depending on which radio button is checked. Hiding/showing them isn't enough because I'm going to use .serialize() at a later point. Should I use .detach() and .append() somehow?

I'm also struggling with how to create one more `variable_price_input`'s than there are years between the start and end date. Should I use `<template>` or .clone() somehow?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#inputStartDate, #inputEndDate").change(function() {

    if ($('#inputStartDate').val() && $('#inputEndDate').val()) {

      var startDate = moment($('#inputStartDate').val());
      var endDate = moment($('#inputEndDate').val());

      var durationMonths = endDate.diff(startDate, 'months');

      $('#durationMonths').text(durationMonths);
      
      var durationYears = endDate.diff(startDate, 'years');
    
      $('#durationYears').text(durationYears);

      if (duration > 12) {
        $('#variablePriceOption').prop("disabled", false);
      } else {
        $('#variablePriceOption').prop("disabled", true);
      }

    }


  });

  $('#variablePriceOption, #fixedPriceOption').change(function() {

    if (this.value == 'fixedPrice') {
      //Logic needed
    } else if (this.value == 'variablePrice') {
      //Logic needed
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputStartDate">Start date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputStartDate" name="land_contract_start_date">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEndDate">End date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputEndDate" name="land_contract_end_date">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">Months between selected dates = <span id="durationMonths"></span>. Years between selected dates = <span id="durationYears"></span>.
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPriceModel">Price model</label>
    <div id="inputPriceModel">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inputPriceModel" id="fixedPriceOption" value="fixedPrice" required checked="checked">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="fixedPriceOption">
          Fixed price
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inputPriceModel" id="variablePriceOption" value="variablePrice" disabled="disabled">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="variablePriceOption">
          Variable price
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group fixedPriceModelFormGroup">
    <label for="fixed_price_input">Fixed price amount</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fixed_price_input" name="land_contract_fixed_annual_price">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have updated/clarified my question now.

Comment: You can use `.detach()` yet you'll want to store that object data someplace if the need arises to create it again.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks! I was thinking about using this solution somehow but I couldn't figure out how to implement it in this case: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_detach_move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you started as far as variable pricing inputs showing for each # of year difference of the calendar dates. The code could be broken out into other functions for handling the display/hiding of elements, etc. You need to move your `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` code above your other JS references to get rid of the errors you're seeing for `bootstrap`.

Also, your `duration` variable should be `durationMonths` for comparing > 12, as `duration` is `undefined`. `durationYears` should be moved outside the `change` function of the calendar dates so you can reference it in your other processing functions. I added `Math.abs()` to the date calculations to ensure you're dealing with a positive integer for comparisons.

Using the `disabled` attribute on the `inputs` that are hidden will allow you to serialize the visible `form` data and ensure you won't get hidden inputs (variable pricing fields, etc) as part of the `serialization` data.

As @Twisty mentioned in the comments on your post, you will want to use `.detach()` or some sort of way to store the variable pricing input values if you toggle back and forth between Fixed/Variable options (`localStorage`, `sessionStorage` also options for storing data), if you want to maintain any values placed in the variable/fixed `inputs`. You will need to remove the `.empty()` usage on the input fields in my example as well, if you intend to store the data values of the inputs.

The loop function `handleVariablePricing` for determining how many variable pricing inputs should show would need to hook into the stored data functionality to ensure you are creating the same amount of fields with previously entered values, and not adding additional new fields on top of the existing fields/values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var durationYears = 0;

  $("#inputStartDate, #inputEndDate").change(function() {

    if ($('#inputStartDate').val() && $('#inputEndDate').val()) {

      var startDate = moment($('#inputStartDate').val());
      var endDate = moment($('#inputEndDate').val());

      var durationMonths = Math.abs(endDate.diff(startDate, 'months'));
      $('#durationMonths').text(durationMonths);

      // maintain value outside of change function
      durationYears = Math.abs(endDate.diff(startDate, 'years'));
      $('#durationYears').text(durationYears);

      if (durationMonths > 12) {
        $('#variablePriceOption').prop("disabled", false);
      } else {
        $('#variablePriceOption').prop("disabled", true);
      }

      // If dates changed, update variable inputs shown
      if ($('#variablePriceOption').is(':checked')) {
        if (durationMonths > 12) {
          $('#variable_price_input_1').val('');
          $('.duration-years-input').remove();
          handleVariablePricing();
        } else {
          $('#fixedPriceOption').click();
        }
      }
    }

  });

  $('#variablePriceOption, #fixedPriceOption').change(function() {

    if (this.value == 'fixedPrice') {

      $('.variablePriceModelFormGroup').removeClass('d-block').addClass('d-none');
      $('.variablePriceModelFormGroup input').each(function() {
        $(this).val('').attr('disabled', true);
      });
      $('.fixedPriceModelFormGroup input').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.fixedPriceModelFormGroup').removeClass('d-none').addClass('d-block');
      $('.duration-years-input').remove();

    } else if (this.value == 'variablePrice') {

      $('.fixedPriceModelFormGroup').removeClass('d-block').addClass('d-none');
      $('.fixedPriceModelFormGroup input').val('').attr('disabled', true);
      $('#variable_price_input_1').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.variablePriceModelFormGroup').removeClass('d-none').addClass('d-block');

      handleVariablePricing();

    }

  });

  /**
   * Creates inputs for variable pricing..
   **/
  var handleVariablePricing = function() {
    $rowClone = $('.row-main').clone();
    for (var i = 2; i <= durationYears + 1; i++) {
      $rowClone.prop('class', 'duration-years-input');
      $rowClone.find('label').text('Price Year ' + i);
      $rowClone.find('input').prop('id', 'variable_price_input_' + i);
      $rowClone.find('input').prop('name', 'land_contract_variable_annual_price_' + i);
      if ($('.duration-years-input').length === 0) {
        $('.row-main').after($rowClone);
      } else {
        $('.duration-years-input').last().after($rowClone);
      }
      $rowClone = $('.duration-years-input').last().clone();
    }
  };

  $('button').click(function() {
    console.log($('#test-form').serialize());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form id="test-form">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputStartDate">Start date</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputStartDate" name="land_contract_start_date">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEndDate">End date</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputEndDate" name="land_contract_end_date">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">Months between selected dates = <span id="durationMonths"></span>. Years between selected dates = <span id="durationYears"></span>.
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPriceModel">Price model</label>
      <div id="inputPriceModel">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inputPriceModel" id="fixedPriceOption" value="fixedPrice" required checked="checked">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="fixedPriceOption">
          Fixed price
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inputPriceModel" id="variablePriceOption" value="variablePrice" disabled="disabled">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="variablePriceOption">
          Variable price
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group fixedPriceModelFormGroup">
      <label for="fixed_price_input">Fixed price amount</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fixed_price_input" name="land_contract_fixed_annual_price">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group variablePriceModelFormGroup d-none">
      <div class="row-main">
        <label for="variable_price_input">Price Year 1</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="variable_price_input_1" name="land_contract_variable_annual_price_1" disabled="disabled">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <button>Serialize</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want an additional input for variable pricing on top of # of years, just add 1 to the durationYears variable for the for loop.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I forgot to mention that the label for each `variable_price_input` need to be descriptive, like "Price year 1", "Price year 2" and so on. Anyway to fix that? Also, how can I have the number of `variable_price_input`´s adjust when #variablePriceOption is checked and the start or end date is changed?

Comment: Another thing, is the custom css needed when using Bootstrap 4? Can't I just use .visible and .invisible? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/visibility/

Comment: Wrong classes in my last comment. I meant .d-none and 
.d-block. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I don't care about keeping the inputted values when toggling so your solution is perfect! Let me know if you think .d-none and .d-block would work instead of custom css. Thank you!

Comment: You're most welcome. I updated snippet with the .d-none/block classes, as yes, that makes more sense to use.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again.

Comment: I just realised that one `variable_price_input` is still showing even if I change "durationYears" to less than 1 by changing start or end date (i.e. when `variable_price_option` gets disabled again). Is there a way to make `fixed_price_option` checked automatically when "durationYears" is less than 1?

Comment: Good Catch! Updated it so if `durationYears` is not > 0, that the Fixed Years option will automatically be clicked and the variable inputs removed, etc.

Comment: If I set start date to "2019-07-22" (I'm in Sweden) and end date to "2020-07-22", the `variable_price_option` is still disabled (which is correct, since the difference is not more than 1 year). If I then change end date to "2020-08-22", the `variable_price_option` is checkable (which is correct, since the difference now more than 1 year). However, if I now change end date back to "2020-07-22", `variable_price_option` is still checked (even though it's disabled) and two `variable_price_input`´s are showing. See screenshot: https://imgur.com/WUYAIPR

Comment: Ah, I see. I updated the snippet so that it checks `if (durationMonths > 12) {` instead of `durationYears` for the `if ($('#variablePriceOption').is(':checked')) {` code block. That's my bad.

Comment: Welcome! Also, I know the serializing is shown as an example, but if you're looking to post the inputs using PHP or another server side language, I would update the code for the variable input fields to have something like `name="variable_pricing[]"` for each one, so you can post the values as an array, etc. Not sure if that might be helpful for what you're doing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm sending the serialized form as a POST request to a PHP file which inserts the data to a MySQL database. There are ten columns in the database for the variable annual pricing: `land_contract_price_year_1`, `land_contract_price_year_2` and so on. I'm pretty sure that's the wrong way to store them but I don't know any other way. Are you suggesting I can store them as an array?

Comment: I created a new question from my last comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161730/storing-an-array-of-unknown-length/57161907.

Comment: I found this article and I now understand what you mean. I went for `$rowClone.find('input').prop('name', 'land_contract_variable_annual_price[year' + i + ']');`. Thanks for the tip! https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/submit-an-array-with-a-html-form/