# Storing an array of unknown length

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, serialization

I'm letting my users add number inputs in a HTML form and filling them with values. The form is serialized on submit and sent to a PHP file that inserts the data into a MySQL database with PDO. The database table has a bunch of columns for storing other values from the form, but the columns for storing the user added inputs are set up like this:

```
input_value_1
input_value_2
input_value_3
input_value_4
...
...
input_value_10
```

These columns allows `NULL` since I don't know if the user will add any number inputs at all.

Is there a better way of storing these numbers?

Below is the part of my JS for getting form data and sending to LandOwners.php which inserts the values to my database. Code is **without** the number inputs (I haven't added them yet since I'm not sure how I should store their data).

```
$("#createLandOwnerForm").on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    createLandOwner($(this).serialize(), appendCreatedLandOwnerToSelect, appendCreatedLandOwnerToSelect_Error);

    $('#createLandOwnerForm')[0].reset();
});

function createLandOwner(landOwner, onSuccess, onError) {    
     var data = landOwner + "&action=create";

     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: host + 'LandOwners.php',
        data: data,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
     });
}
```

Below is the part of LandOwners.php which is inserting to mydatabase **without** the number inputs (I haven't added them yet since I'm not sure I how/if should).

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO land_owner (land_owner_name, land_owner_identification_number, land_owner_contact, land_owner_phone, land_owner_email, land_contracts) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute([$land_owner_name, $land_owner_identification_number, $land_owner_contact, $land_owner_phone, $land_owner_email, $land_contracts]);

$last_inserted_land_owner_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM land_owner WHERE land_owner_id = ?");
$stmt->execute([$last_inserted_land_owner_id]);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $arr[] = $row;
}

if(!$arr) exit('No rows');

echo json_encode($arr);

$stmt = null;
```

Below is the part of LandOwners.php that selects data from my database. I want to (still be able to) get the result as JSON.

```
$arr = [];

if (isset($_POST["land_owner_id"])){
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM land_owner WHERE land_owner_id = ?");
  $stmt->execute([$land_owner_id]);
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM land_owner");
    $stmt->execute();
}

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $arr[] = $row;
}

if(!$arr) exit('No rows');

echo json_encode($arr);

$stmt = null;
break;
```

Comment: Yes, you should instead have a table with the values and a relation to whatever they're related to - more simple rows instead of many repeating columns is better.

Comment: @Qirel So I should replace the ten columns with a new column called `input_values` and relate that to a new table with a foreign key? If that is correct, what should `input_values` look like if someone added 15 inputs and how should the new table be structured? Thanks!

Comment: @Qirel I have updated my question with my currect code. How would it have to be changed?

Comment: Create a `land_owner_input` and put all the inputs there on separate rows, with a reference to the unique identifier of `land_owner` (the ID, probably).

Comment: Is this the way you mean the setup of the tables should look like? https://i.imgur.com/CESnTyF.png

Comment: Looks great! That way you can have an endless, unspecified amount of inputs for each `land_owner`.

Comment: Perfect! If you add this as answer instead of a comment I'll accept it but that's up to you of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself in a situation where you start having `column1`, `column2` on the table - chances are that your design is getting flawed, and you should instead create a separate table - where each `columnX` gets a row of its own. It's (nearly) always better to have a separate table if you find yourself having multiple repeating columns on the same table.

That way, you avoid storing comma-separated values in columns, you avoid breaking your code/queries if you suddenly have to introduce another value `column{X+1}` - and instead can have as many or as few input-values as you need to.

For you, that would be something like a new table called `land_owner_input`, where you have the value (that you would put in `columnX`), and a reference to the row in `land_owner` that the value belongs to.

Typical design pattern would be something like this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE land_owner_input (
    land_owner_input_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
    land_owner_id INT(11), 
    land_owner_input_value VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

Keep in mind that your `land_owner_id` in the new table should be of the exact same type and size as the ID its referencing.

You can also create a foreign key constraint between the `land_owner_id` and the ID of the `land_owner` table to ensure data integrity.

Once you have your new table, you can query them together by using a `LEFT JOIN` (or a normal `JOIN` if you only want to return rows if it has input-values).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM land_owner AS lo
LEFT JOIN land_owner_input AS loi
    ON loi.land_owner_id = lo.land_owner_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate your time and help!

Comment: I'm using your solution to store my data but I've been struggling for many hours with a problem related to it. Can you please have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57209240/1711950

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cold have one column, json type, and store json in it?

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_table
(
  `json` JSON NOT NULL
  ) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And than you can store JSON to this column, like:

```
{"input_value_1":1, "input_value_2",...."input_value_10":10}
```

You culd than easily get single value (assuming they will always have same keys) with JSON_EXTRACT:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json,'$.input_value_'.$x) FROM some_table WHERE some_condition
```

Comment: I have updated my question with my currect code. How would it have to be changed?